# Why does the sqlParameter request a sourceColumn?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, parameters, sqlcommand

I was examining a sqlParameter [example](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldataadapter.selectcommand.aspx) from Microsoft and am trying to understand:

**What are the reasons and benefits for specifying a [SourceColumn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlparameter.sourcecolumn%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)?**

*The sql command already specifies the target column.*

```
    command = New SqlCommand( _
        "INSERT INTO Customers (CustomerID, CompanyName) " & _
        "VALUES (@CustomerID, @CompanyName)", connection)

    command.Parameters.Add("@CustomerID", SqlDbType.NChar, 5, "CustomerID")
    command.Parameters.Add("@CompanyName", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 40, "CompanyName")
```

[image]

Comment: i don't get the question. The adapter has to know somehow which column to use in order to set values.

Comment: @Aツ: imo this is a fair question. I've never used this property although i use ADO.NET for 14 years

Comment: @Aツ In the example above the insert statement provides the source column.

Comment: "The sql command already specifies the target column." - yes, but the name of this parameter/property is *source* column. Which column *from the `DataSet`* should be used to populate this parameter when the `DataAdapter` is automatically populating and using the command that this parameter is attached to?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Specifying the `SourceColumn` in this instance means specifying the column name property (`DataColumn.ColumnName`) in a `DataTable` or `Dataset`.  This is only important when you're using a `SqlDataAdapter` object in conjunction with your `SqlCommand` like so:

```
--first, fill a DataTable with data from the database:
Dim dt As New DataTable
Dim cmdSelect = New SqlCommand("SELECT CustomerID, CompanyName FROM Customers;", connection)
Dim daCustomers As New SqlDataAdapter
daCustomers.SelectCommand = cmdSelect
daCustomers.Fill(dt)

--Now our DataTable has two columns: "CustomerID" and "CompanyName"
--We can help out our DataAdapter by telling it which columns in the database
--correspond with which columns in the DataTable 
--which is what you've done with your fourth argument of .Parameters.Add()
command = New SqlCommand( _
    "INSERT INTO Customers (CustomerID, CompanyName) " & _
    "VALUES (@CustomerID, @CompanyName)", connection)

command.Parameters.Add("@CustomerID", SqlDbType.NChar, 5, "CustomerID")
command.Parameters.Add("@CompanyName", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 40, "CompanyName")
daCustomers.InsertCommand = command
```

If we do it this way, then we won't have to ever specify the values of the two parameters (in this case, when the `InsertCommand` fires), because the data adapter will just look at the values in the appropriate `DataColumn` & `DataRow` automatically when you call `daCustomers.Update(dt)`.

Likewise, if you want your `SqlDataAdapter` to be even more useful, you would want to also specify the `SourceColumn` for the parameters of your defined `UpdateCommand` and `DeleteCommand`s.  Note that a lot of people prefer to use a `SqlCommandBuilder` [object to automatically configure](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommandbuilder(v=vs.110).aspx) their `SqlDataAdapters` for this and other simple adapters without specifying much of anything for their `SqlCommand` objects, but I prefer this more explicit approach for anything but the simplest cases.

I am unaware of any benefit to be gained by specifying `SourceColumn` when you're **not using** a `SqlDataAdapter` with your `SqlCommand`.